# difucltad con función constructora con metodos JS

Tags: javascript-metodo

Este es un ejercicio de JavaScript.

El problema que estoy teniendo es en getAlcance y getTraducciones.

Estoy consciente de que hay muchos problemas en mi código pero no tengo los conocimientos como para poder hacer que funcione.

PD: No logré ser capaz de corregir los errores que aparecen en mi VSC por falta de conocimientos y experiencia. De todas maneras, investigué por todos lados pero tampoco encontré información relacionada al tema.

```
    function crearClaseLibro() {
  class Libro {
    constructor(titulo, autor, traducciones) {
      // El constructor de la clase Libro recibe titulo (string), autor (string), traducciones (array de objetos)
      // Inicializar las propiedades del libro con los valores recibidos como argumento
      // Tu código aca:
      this.titulo = titulo,
      this.autor =  autor,
      this.traducciones = traducciones
    }

    getTitulo() {
      // este método debe retornar el titulo del libro.
      // Tu código aca:
      return this.titulo;
    }

    getAutor() {
      // El método debe retornar nombre y apellido del autor
      // Tu código aca:
      return this.autor.nombre + ' ' + this.autor.apellido;
    }

    addTraduccion(idioma, editorial) {
      // El método recibe un string 'idioma' y un string 'editorial' y debe agregar un objeto:
      // { idioma: idioma, editorial: editorial} al arreglo de traducciones del libro.
      // No debe retornar nada.
      // Tu código aca:
      let nuevaTraduccion = {
        idioma: idioma,
        editorial: editorial
      };
      this.traducciones.push(nuevaTraduccion);
  }
    }

    getTraducciones() {
      // El método debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los idiomas del arreglo de traducciones del libro.
      // Ej:
      // Suponiendo que el libro tiene estas traducciones: [{idioma: 'inglés', editorial: 'Scholastic'}, {idioma: 'castellano', editorial: 'Santillana'}]
      // libro.getTraducciones() debería devolver ['inglés', 'castellano']
      // Tu código aca:
      let idiomasTraducciones = ((book) => book.traducciones);
      let listaTraducciones = this.traducciones.map(idiomasTraducciones);
      return listaTraducciones;
    }

    getAlcance() {
      // El metodo debe retornar la cantidad de idiomas en la que esta traducido el libro.
      // Dato: no se repiten ni los idiomas ni las editoriales
      // ej:
      // Suponiendo que el libro tiene estas traducciones: [{idioma: 'inglés', editorial: 'Scholastic'}, {idioma: 'castellano', editorial: 'Santillana'}]
      // libro.getAlcance() deberia devolver 2
      // Tu código aca:
      let cantidadIdioma = (' ');
      for (let i = 0; i < this.traducciones.length; i++) {
        if ((book) === this.traducciones[i].idioma) {
          cantidadIdioma = this.traducciones[i].editorial;
        }
      } return cantidadIdioma;
    }
  return Libro;
}´
```

Comment: getAutor, revisala (no te dan nombre y apellido, te dan solo el autor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dijeron si no se repiten los idiomas todos son unicos asique con la longitud del array traducciones es suficiente:

```
class Libro{

  constructor(titulo, autor, traducciones){
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.traducciones = traducciones;
  }

  getTitulo(){
    return this.titulo;
  }

  getAutor(){
    return this.autor; // si autor es un string debe ser "nombre + apellido", tal y como hiciste el metodo esta mal porque autor no es un objeto y la consigna dice que es un string
  }

  addTraduccion(traduccion){
    this.traducciones.push(traduccion)
  }

  getTraducciones(){
    let langs = [] // array auxiliar
    this.traducciones.forEach(element => { // para cada objeto traduccion
      langs.push(element.idioma) // agregamos el idioma de la traduccion al array
    });
    return langs; // devolvemos el array
  }

  getAlcance(){
    return this.traducciones.length; // si no se repiten los idiomas ni las traducciones entonces solo habria que devolver la longitud del array
  }
}
```

fuera de la clase:

```
let libro = new Libro( // declaracion de un Libro
  "El Lunatico y su hermana Libertad",
  "Paul Kropp",[
    { idioma: "Español", editorial: "Sol Nuevo" },
    { idioma: "Chino", editorial: "Eucalipto" },
    { idioma: "Ingles", editorial: "Minotaur" },    
    { idioma: "Frances", editorial: "Delvaux" },
    { idioma: "Portugues", editorial: "Lisboa ltd" },
  ]
)

console.log(libro.getAutor())
console.log(libro.getTitulo())
libro.addTraduccion({idioma: "Japones", editorial: "Takashi"}) // agregamos una traduccion y comprobamos:
console.log(libro.getTraducciones())
console.log(libro.getAlcance())
```

cualquier duda solo pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto y te agradezco las explicaciones paso por paso, ayudan a entender mejor lo que hacia mal